# How to use Unicode::Normalize to create most compatible windows-1252 encoded string?

Tags: string, perl, unicode, utf-8

I have a legacy app in Perl processing XML encoded in `UTF-8` most likely and which needs to store some data of that XML in some database, which uses `windows-1252` for historical reasons. Yes, this setup can't support all possible characters of the Unicode standard, but in practice I don't need to anyway and can try to be reasonable compatible.

The specific problem currently is a file containing `LATIN SMALL LETTER U, COMBINING DIAERESIS` (`U+0075 U+0308`), which makes Perl break the existing encoding of the Unicode string to `windows-1252` with the following exception:

> "\x{0308}" does not map to cp1252

I was able to work around that problem using [Unicode::Normalize::NFKC](https://perldoc.perl.org/Unicode/Normalize.html#Normalization-Forms), which creates the character `U+00FC` (`ü`), which perfectly fine maps to `windows-1252`. That lead to some other problem of course, e.g. in case of the character `VULGAR FRACTION ONE HALF` (`½`, `U+00BD`), because `NFKC` creates `DIGIT ONE, FRACTION SLASH, DIGIT TWO` (`1/2`, `U+0031 U+2044 U+0032`) for that and Perl dies again:

> "\x{2044}" does not map to cp1252

According to [normalization rules](https://www.unicode.org/charts/normalization/chart_Number-Other.html), this is perfectly fine for `NFKC`. I used that because I thought it would give me the most compatible result, but that was wrong. Using `NFC` instead fixed both problems, as both characters provide a [normalization](https://www.unicode.org/charts/normalization/chart_Latin.html) compatible with `windows-1252` in that case.

This approach gets additionally problematic for characters for which a normalization compatible with  `windows-1252` is available in general, only different from `NFC`. One example is `LATIN SMALL LIGATURE FI` (`ﬁ`, `U+FB01`). According to it's [normalization rules](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/#Norm_Forms), it's representation after `NFC` is incompatible with `windows-1252`, while using `NFKC` this time results in two characters compatible with `windows-1252`: `fi` (`U+0066 U+0069`).

My current approach is to simply try encoding as `windows-1252` as is, if that fails I'm using `NFC` and try again, if that fails I'm using `NFKC` and try again and if that fails I'm giving up for now. This works in the cases I'm currently dealing with, but obviously fails if all three characters of my examples above are present in a string at the same time. There's always one character then which results in `windows-1252`-incompatible output, regardless the order of `NFC` and `NFKC`. The only question is which character breaks when.

BUT the important point is that each character by itself could be normalized to something being compatible with `windows-1252`. It only seems that there's no one-shot-solution.

**So, is there some API I'm missing, which already converts in the most backwards compatible way?**

**If not, what's the approach I would need to implement myself to support all the above characters within one string?**

Sounds like I would need to process each string Unicode-character by Unicode-character, normalize individually with what is most compatible with `windows-1252` and than concatenate the results again. Is there some incremental Unicode-character parser available which deals with combining characters and stuff already? Does a simple Unicode-character based regular expression handles this already?

`Unicode::Normalize` provides additional functions to work on [partial strings](https://perldoc.perl.org/Unicode/Normalize.html#Decomposition-and-Composition) and such, but I must admit that I currently don't fully understand their purpose. The examples focus on concatenation as well, but from my understanding I first need some parsing to be able to normalize individual characters differently.

Comment: Can you do it by-character, in those cases when the conversion for the whole string (word I presume) breaks down?  It does read utf-8 correctly (right?), so you have the characters.  Not pretty perhaps but it should take care of it?

Comment: What's your suggestion of splitting some string into individual Unicode-characters while properly dealing with combining chars and stuff? I'm a bit unsure currently about that part.

Comment: Since it seems that your have the conversion (to cp-1252 encoding) itself under control, I assume that it is about identifying a "character" for conversion, with all the Unicode marks and whatnot. That'd be `\X` in regex, which matches the logical character (as either single or multiple codepoints).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you're missing an API because a best-effort approach is rather involved. I'd try something like the following:

- Normalize using NFC. This combines decomposed sequences like LATIN SMALL LETTER U, COMBINING DIAERESIS.
- Extract all codepoints which aren't combining marks using the regex `/\PM/g`. This throws away all combining marks remaining after NFC conversion which can't be converted to Windows-1252 anyway. Then for each code point:

  - If the codepoint can be converted to Windows-1252, do so.
  - Otherwise try to normalize the codepoint with NFKC. If the NFKC mapping differs from the input, apply all steps recursively on the resulting string. This handles things like ligatures.
  - As a bonus: If the codepoint is invariant under NFKC, convert to NFD and try to convert the first codepoint of the result to Windows-1252. This converts characters like Ĝ to G.
  - Otherwise ignore the character.

There are of course other approaches that convert unsupported characters to ones that look similar but they require to create mappings manually.

Comment: Accepted this answer for now because it was first and seems to be the more complete recipe regarding my question about a "most compatible" way.

Answer (score 2):

Since it seems that you can convert individual characters as needed (to cp-1252 encoding), one way is to process character by character, as proposed, once a word fails the procedure.

The `\X` in Perl's regex matches a *logical* Unicode character, an [extended grapheme cluster](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html#Extended-Grapheme-Clusters-%28Logical-characters%29), either as a single codepoint or a sequence. So if you indeed can convert all individual (logical) characters into the desired encoding, then with

```
while ($word =~ /(\X)/g) { ... }
```

you can access the logical characters and apply your working procedure to each.

In case you can't handle all logical characters that may come up, piece together an equivalent of `\X` using specific [character properties](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html#Unicode-Character-Properties), for finer granularity with combining marks or such (like `/((.)\p{Mn}?)/`, or `\p{Nonspacing_Mark}`). The full, grand, list is in [perluniprops](https://perldoc.perl.org/perluniprops.html).

Comment: @DragosTrif  If the comment is meant for OP you should have at-username so that they get notified (like I have in this one).  Either way, I fully assumed that they have the actual conversion down, and that their problem was that their procedure may fail for whole words since it may not work the same way for all characters in the word; that's what the question states really.  If that is indeed the case then the post you kindly link doesn't help them (it is certainly not needed for this answer).

Comment: @zdim Reading about `Text::Unidecode` was interesting, though. Nevertheless, what is `\p{cM}` in your answer? I couldn't find that, only `\p{Mc}` for `Spacing_Mark`. Simply a typo?

Comment: @ThorstenSchöning  Indeed, a bad typo, I meant the Nonspacing_Mark -- thank you! Fixed